# Transfer a parameter to Lambda via ssm document

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I am looking for a way to transfer a parameter to a lambda function from a ssm document.
The below setup works if I am using a simple string, but when I use a parameter in the format of `{{InstanceId}}` I get an error - parameter is not defined.
What  is the correct format for passing a parameter via ssm document  ?

```
parameters:
  InstanceId:
    type: String
mainSteps:
  - name: stepName
    action: 'aws:invokeLambdaFunction'
    inputs:
      InvocationType: RequestResponse
      FunctionName: Name_Function
      InputPayload: InstanceId:{{InstanceId}}
    timeoutSeconds: 120
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found it:
This is how to do it , for those who struggle with it...

```
 Payload: '{"InstanceId": "{{InstanceId}}"}'
```